# Set merge strategy on AndoridManifest when using gradle and library projects

Tags: android, merge, android-manifest, android-gradle-plugin

I have a gradle project that uses a library with a minSdkVersion set to api level 11. My application has a minSdkVersion of 9. When compiling I get the following error.

```
Main manifest has <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion='9'> but library uses minSdkVersion='11'
```

I have seen a similar question titled [manifest-merging-failed-android-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21184788/manifest-merging-failed-android-studio) but the solution was to change the library to have the same minSdk version. If you dont have control over the library that isnt possible.

The library is only used in situations where the minSdkVersion is higher than 11 so actual use isnt an issue.

Is there anyway to get the advantages manifest merging and let the library have a higher minSdk than your main project?

Workarounds that I have thought of but havent found a way to do.

1. Set priority if manifests conflict
2. Ignore minsdk for library projects
3. Remove minSdk from arr before merging starts